# Calculated summary field based on child table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I have two tables, `Order` and `OrderItem`. There is a one-to-many relationship on `Order.Order_ID=OrderItem.Order_ID`

I want a query to return a list showing the status of each Order, COMPLETE or INCOMPLETE.

A COMPLETE Order is defined as one where all the related OrderItem records have a non-`NULL`, non-empty value in the `OrderItem.Delivery_ID` field.

This is what I have so far:

```
  SELECT Order.Order_ID, 'INCOMPLETE' AS Order_status
  FROM Order 
  WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM OrderItem 
     WHERE OrderItem.Order_ID=Order.Order_ID 
     AND (OrderItem.Delivery_ID IS NULL OR OrderItem.Delivery_ID=''))
UNION 
  SELECT Order.Order_ID, 'COMPLETE' AS Order_status
  FROM Order 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM OrderItem 
     WHERE OrderItem.Order_ID=Order.Order_ID 
     AND (OrderItem.Delivery_ID IS NULL OR OrderItem.Delivery_ID=''))
ORDER BY Order_ID DESC
```

It works, but runs a bit slow. Is there a better way?

(N.B. I've restated the problem for clarity, actual table and field names are different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you have a column *status* on your Order table and update the status to complete when all order items get delivered.

It will make simple your query to get status as well improve performance.

Comment: We actually have one, but sadly the OrderItem records get updated all over the place and we cannot trust it. I need to calculate it every time for now.

Comment: You can have a trigger on the order item to do the update on status, but you need to be careful within performance on it. Another suggestion would be add an index on **orderitem.delivery_id** and it will probably make your query faster.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer. It doesn't actually help my specific problem, but it is the best general solution.

Answer (score 1):

Put it into a subquery to try to make the case statement less confusing:

```
SELECT Order_ID,
       CASE WHEN incomplete_count > 0 THEN 'INCOMPLETE' ELSE 'COMPLETE' END
           AS Order_status

  FROM ( SELECT o.Order_ID
               ,SUM( CASE WHEN OrderItem.Delivery_ID IS NULL OR OrderItem.Delivery_ID='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
                 AS incomplete_count
           FROM Order o 
           INNER JOIN OrderItem i ON (i.Order_ID = o.Order_ID)
           GROUP by o.Order_ID
       ) x

   ORDER BY ORder_ID DESC
```

The idea is to keep a counter every time you encounter a null item. If the sum is 0, there were no empty order items.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
SELECT 
       o.Order_ID
     , Order_status = 
               CASE WHEN ot.Order_ID IS NULL 
                    THEN 'COMPLETE' 
                    ELSE 'INCOMPLETE' 
               END
FROM dbo.[Order] o
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT DISTINCT ot.Order_ID
     FROM dbo.OrderItem ot
     WHERE ISNULL(ot.Delivery_ID, '') = '' 
) ot ON ot.Order_ID = o.Order_ID
```